# Merging SharePoint Word documents into a single PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, sharepoint

I created a program which collects all the word files from a folder which belongs to our SharePoint library of documents. The program will only grab the documents if they were submitted/are a part of the HR team.

These documents are saved in a temporary folder, and then merged together into one large pdf.

I thought this seemed a bit superfluous, and figured there must be a way of achieving this without having to save the individual pdf files first. Ideally I would also like a way of dynamically creating a table of contents based on the files which are already present.

The files need to be in the correct order, so each document on SharePoint has been assigned an order number.

This list is retrieved so that I have something to order the documents against (as saving them in the file results in them being in their default, alphabetical order, appending the order number to the beginning of the file name also doesn't work, as this orders them as 1, 10, 11, 12 .. etc). I also feel that this can be improved upon. If I can work out how to convert the word files into PDFs without having to save them first, I could sort the FileInfo data before converting.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how I can improve/implement the above, or any other comments? Any  advice/guidance at all is much appreciated.

**Program**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace PdfConverter
{
    class Program
    {
        #region fields
            public static List<string> orderedList;
        #endregion fields

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get the word files FileInfo
            FileInfo[] wordFileInfo = DataGrabber.GetWordFileInfo();

            // Instantiate a new 'Convert' object and convert our files to pdf, saving them in a temporary folder
            Converter convert = new Converter();
            convert.ToPdf(wordFileInfo);

            // Get the pdf filenames
            var newPdfFiles = DataGrabber.GetPdfFileNames();

            convert.MergePdfs(newPdfFiles);

            // Delete the files
            foreach (var item in orderedList)
            {
                var newFileName = "\\\\file\\IT\\SK\\test\\" + item.Split('.')[0] + ".pdf";
                System.IO.File.Delete(newFileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DataGrabber**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


namespace PdfConverter
{
    class DataGrabber
    {
        #region fields
            public static string spSite = "http://SharepointSite/WorkingHere";
            public static string policyList = "Policies & Procedures";
            public static string sortBy = "Sort_x0020_Order";
            public static string sourceFolder = @"\\SharepointSite\WorkingHere\PoliciesandProcedures"; \\ network SP folder
        #endregion fields

        public ListItemCollection GetSpList(string siteName, string listName, string sortBy)
        {
            // Set the context (URL) of the site ...
            ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(siteName);
            Web web = cc.Web;

            // Get the list by title
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

            // A query to fileter the results
            CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
            caml.ViewXml = "<View>" +
                                "<Query>" +
                                    "<OrderBy>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name='" + sortBy + "' Ascending='True'/>" +
                                    "</OrderBy>" +
                                "</Query>" +
                            //"<RowLimit>" + strCount + "</RowLimit>" +
                            "</View>";

            // Store the items  in a ListItemCollection
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(caml);

            // Load the client context and execute
            cc.Load<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List>(list);
            cc.Load<ListItemCollection>(items);

            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            return items;
        }

        public static FileInfo[] GetWordFileInfo()
        {
            // Create a new data grabber
            DataGrabber d = new DataGrabber();
            // Get the SP list using spList - policyList - sortBy
            ListItemCollection spList = d.GetSpList(spSite, policyList, sortBy);
            // Get a list of the document titles from spList
            List<string> hrDocTitles = d.Sort(spList);
            // Get the fileinfo from these documents
            FileInfo[] wordFiles = d.GetFiles(hrDocTitles);

            return wordFiles;
        }

        public FileInfo[] GetFiles(List<string> fileNames)
        {
            // Get the fileinfo from each document we added to the docList 
            var length = fileNames.Count;

            string uriPath = sourceFolder;

            FileInfo[] wordFiles = new FileInfo[length];

            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                string path = uriPath + "\\" + fileNames[j];
                string localPath = new Uri(path).LocalPath;
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localPath);

                wordFiles[j] = fileInfo;
            }

            return wordFiles;
        }

        public List<string> Sort(ListItemCollection spList)
        {
            List<string> docList = new List<string>();

            // For each item in the SPList, check if it is HR and then add it to our lists
            foreach (ListItem litem in spList)
            {
                try
                {
                    var rawTeam = litem.FieldValues["BRTeamHTField0"].ToString();

                    var team = rawTeam.Substring(0, 2);
                    var asd = litem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"];
                    string title = "";

                    if (team == "HR" & litem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString().Contains(".doc"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            title = litem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            title = ""; 
                        }
                        docList.Add(title);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Nothing
                    }
                }
                catch 
                {

                }
            }
            // Update the ordered list field in the main program - used to maintain the correct document order
            Program.orderedList = docList;
            return docList;
        }

        public static string[] GetPdfFileNames()
        {
            // Get list of word files in specified directory
            string localPath = new Uri(sourceFolder).LocalPath;

            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(localPath);
            FileInfo[] pdfFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            var length = pdfFiles.Length; // To exclude the existing HR Policies and Procedures Guide
            string[] pdfFileNames = new string[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                pdfFileNames[i] = localPath + "\\" + pdfFiles[i].Name;
            }

            Array.Sort(pdfFileNames);
            return pdfFileNames;
        }
    }
}
```

**Converter**

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PdfConverter
{
    class Converter
    {
        #region fields
            public static string tempTargetFolder = @"\\file\IT\SK\test\";
            public static string targetPdf = @"\\file\IT\SK\test\Guide\testOutput.pdf";
        #endregion fields

        public void ToPdf(FileInfo[] wordFiles)
        {
            // Takes a FileInfo[] variable and convers each file in it to pdf, saving it to a temporary target folder tempTargetFolder
            // Create a new microsoft word application object
            Application word = new Application();

            word.Visible = false;
            word.ScreenUpdating = false;

            // I think this can actually be done away with and all oMissing parameters removed, as C# can handle optional parameters ...
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            // for adding the file name to the temporary pdf files
            int counter = 1;

            foreach (FileInfo wordFile in wordFiles)
            {
                // Cast as object for word open method
                Object fileName = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                doc.Activate();

                object outputFileName = new object();
                if (wordFile.FullName.Contains(".docx"))
                {
                    outputFileName = tempTargetFolder + wordFile.FullName.Split('\\')[5];
                    outputFileName = outputFileName.ToString().Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
                }
                else if (wordFile.FullName.Contains(".doc"))
                {
                    outputFileName = tempTargetFolder + wordFile.FullName.Split('\\')[5];
                    outputFileName = outputFileName.ToString().Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

                object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                // Save document into pdf format
                doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                    ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                // Close the word document, but leave the word application open.
                // Doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
                // correct close method.
                object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc = null;

                counter++;
            }

            // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find the correct Quit method
            ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            word = null;
        }

        public void MergePdfs(string[] newPdfFiles)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create))
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);

                PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();

                foreach (string file in Program.orderedList)
                {
                    var newFileName = "\\\\file\\IT\\SK\\test\\" + file.Split('.')[0] + ".pdf";
                    PdfReader test = new PdfReader(newFileName);
                    pdf.AddDocument(test);
                    test.Dispose();
                }

                // pdfDoc.Close(); // Doesn't seem to do anything
                pdf.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orderedList`: you should not have public fields in your class. Is it OK if someone else **assigns** an entirely new value to that field? If not then you should make a property with private setter. Also name isn't so helpful: orderer list of what? Even better: remove it. Static fields, properties and methods are terrible to test and in this case you don't even need it because it can be a function return value.

`newFileName` is built manually with an hard-coded constant (move it to a `const` private field) and a manually parsed file name. To obtain file name (it doesn't matter how trivial it *seems*) you should use `Path` methods, in this case `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`. It's both clear (to readers) and more reliable.

In my opinion your `Main()` method does little bit too many things. Why don't you extract few self-descriptive methods like `ConvertPdf()`, `MergePdf()` and `DeletePdf()`? It's a short method but we have too read (and understand) too much code just to have a coarse overview or program logic.

---

`DataGrabber` class isn't derived. Why don't you also mark it as `sealed`?

Many `static string`s are constants, why don't you declare them as `private const string`?

`sortBy` is an escaped XML fragment and you build XML document with string concatenation. Assuming `sortBy` won't change (make it clear making it `const string`) it's too error-prone and not human-friendly (IMO). You'd better move your XML file into resources, reading it with `XmlDocument.Load()` from `ResourceManager.GetStream()`. You can change attribute value using a simple XPath query. It's slower that *raw* manual approach but easier to read (also  because you don't *pollute* your C# code with XML fragments) and less error-prone (`XmlDocument` will escape things for you).

`ClientContext` class implements `IDisposable` then I'd wrap its usage with `using` (to correctly dispose it also in case of errors).

`Sort()` code is too long and convoluted, in my opinion it needs to be more self-descriptive. What it is doing? What all those fields are?

I'd also change how you manage exceptions, for example:

```
try
{
    title = litem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    title = ""; 
}
```

Why that code may fail? Check instead of catch exceptions (C# is not Python) and for sure never ever catch base `Exception`. If there may be an error you can't prevent then catch exactly that exception otherwise it will hide possible bugs. On the same style: do not ever use `catch { }`. Never, no exceptions to this.

In your `GetPdfFileNames()` the `length` local variable (and its associated comment) are pretty useless. What's its purpose? Why don't you simply use `pdfFiles.Length`? As it is now it doesn't *exclude* anything, is it a bug or an outdated comment?

Also consider to use some LINQ, it may make your code slightly more readable. Note that you do that `for` just to concatenate `FileInfo.Name` with `localPath` however (because `FileInfo` are retrieved from a `DirectoryInfo` created from `localPath`) you already have that value in `FileInfo.FullName` property. One step more: to get full path you don't even need `FileInfo`:

```
var pdfFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(localPath, "*.pdf");
```

---

In `Converter` I'd change more or less same things I already suggested for other modules. Do not build path by hand, to change extension you can use `Path.ChangeExtension()`. Also always (especially when working with Word instances!) use using statement when applicable (also read [How to release COM handle in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9868091/1207195).)

---

Next (optional!) step would be to make your utility more testable and extensible. The fact you're converting using iTextSharp and that documents come from SharePoint are merely implementation details. If you hide this in abstract base classes (or interfaces) you may plug-in (for example) different sources and also test all your logic mocking-up class currently not under-test. As very final note I'd add some sort of *retry-pattern*. Things may go wrong with networks but a temporary error may be recovered if you wait few seconds (and you won't need to restart whole process from beginning), see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014282/1207195).

Comment: Hi Adriano, many thanks for your useful answer. I am currently working my way through your suggestions and trying to improve my solution, but I was having some trouble understanding your first point about setting a private field and a private setter. If my field is private, it cannot be accessed by DataGrabber or Converter. if I set a property `public static List<string>orderedListOfWordFiles { get {return orderedListWordFilesField;} private set{orderedListWordFilesField = value;} }` My DataGrabber cannot assign the value to the field once it has the order.

Comment: Exactly! Use AddRange() if it's a List<T> otherwise make a public property (not field) of string[]. Even better REMOVE it, accessing a static field will make your code hard or impossible to test. Sorted list may simply be a function return value.

Comment: Thank Adriano, but unfortunately I am still confused. You are saying that I should not be able to access that field from another class, but that I how my code currently works. Are you suggesting I pass values back and forth with method calls/signatures rather than trying to access the values from another class (even if this is done through a property rather than a field)?

Comment: Yes. Better to pass value (if it can't be designed in another way) .  Think about a public static field as a global variable in - let's say -  C. It has exactly same drawbacks. Of course in this small example the most obvious one is testability. Don't you feel strange to have objects (then instances) that share data through a static variable?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is wrong, in my experience I have always had a need to have a public static field which can be accessed by other classes, but if this is bad practice I will need to stop doing it! I am thinking of splitting the whole thing out into some more classes (e.g. GetSpList), maybe this will give me a better understanding

Comment: Usually, but it's just in my personal experience, I find easy to first describe what I want to do in plain English (actually in Italian) absolutely without any implementation detail. From that I pick keywords and I make them my base (often abstract) classes. Then I go with implementation. Globals are bad because anyone anywhere can modify them. Synchronization is a pain, classes become top coupled and testing is absolutely a nightmare (when not even impossible).

Comment: It doesn't mean you can't use them but more often than not (I don't believe in axioms in our job) there is another better designed and even easier solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34531/discussion-between-bassie-and-adriano-repetti).